# Android accessibility: TalkBack reading order for a custom view and a TextView

Tags: android, accessibility, android-a11y

I'm trying to improve the a11y in our app and we have the following piece of XML:

```
    <myapp.custom.CurrencyTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/s16"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/s16"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/s2"
        app:intPartTextSize="@dimen/num01FontSize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvAvailableToSpend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:symbolTextSize="@dimen/caption01FontSize"
        app:textColor="@color/accountAmount01" />

    <myapp.custom.NoPaddingTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCurrentBalanceTitle"
        style="@style/caption01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/s4"
        android:accessibilityTraversalBefore="@id/tvBalance"
        android:labelFor="@id/tvBalance"
        android:text="@string/home_balance_spent"
        android:textColor="@color/accountAmount02"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvBalance"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvBalance" />
```

what I'm trying to do is to have TalkBack first read the second view `tvCurrentBalanceTitle` and then the first `tvBalance` but it's impossible in XML (easy to do in Compose though with the `Modifier.semantics` and `traversalGroup`).

I have tried with and without `labelFor` and using `accessibilityTraversalBefore` and after, but I can't make it work.

Am I doing something wrong with the XML?

Comment: Clarify "first read the second view ... and then the first". Do you want "currentBalance" to be focused / read when you first land on the screen? Then when user swipes for the next item, to land on "balance"?